# If f(n) = O(g(n)), is log(f(n)) = O(log(g(n))?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I just learnt today that this relation does not hold, because log changes the behavior of the functions. But is it true? An example will be good.

And also if f(n) = ϴ(g(n)), will log(f(n)) = ϴ(log(g(n)) hold?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think the complexity of the `log()` function is?

Comment: log() will reduce heavily the value returned by f(n) and g(n). So, what's wrong with log(f(n)) = O(log(g(n)))? It should hold too, since at any cost value of log(g(n)) > log(f(n))!

Comment: I think we should clarify, are you talking about the time complexity to calculate the function (which is the context in which Big O notation is often used in computer science), or are you talking about the limiting behavior of the function itself?

Comment: @TimGoodman, I'm talking about the time complexity, that is if taking log will also make the relation hold good.

Comment: OK, so you're saying (roughly) "It ought to be quicker to calculate the log of a function than to calculate the function itself", yes?  If so, can you clarify why you think this would be true?  Note that the time complexity doesn't need to be proportional to the size of the output.  Also, note that you can't pass arbitrary functions through the logarithm (that is, `log(F(x)) != F(log(x))`).  Without knowing more about your reasoning, I'm not sure if one or the other of those notes is more relevant to your thought process here.

Comment: It is true if g(n) >= 2, false otherwise (due to the log behaviour near 1)

Comment: Also note that if you find you can calculate `log(f(n))` and then apply a single exponentiation more quickly than you can calculate `f(n)`, then you've just found a faster way to calculate `f(n)`.

Comment: @TimGoodman, I'm sorry. Yes you are correct. Just one more doubt, that is if I take Limit over f(n)/g(n) and log(f(n))/log(g(n)) will both yield same results always like (constant, 0 or infinity)? So, that the limiting behavior as you pointed out earlier will be identical? From which I may conclude that in both cases it maintains similar asymptotic notations?

Comment: First I should clarify (since I notice now that I muddied the waters a bit with my last comment), time complexity generally refers to a *particular algorithm*, not *any possible algorithm for computing the result of a mathematical function". (But when people talk about the somewhat related idea of if a problem belongs to a complexity class such as P or NP, then they're talking about "any algorithm that solves the problem".)  There are certainly cases where one algorithm for calculating `f(n)` is slower than a different algorithm which first calculates `log(f(n)` and then exponentiates it.

Comment: OK;   your are interested in asymptotic limits, not algorithmic complexity (before you edited it, your question as worded appeared about algorithmic complexity).   Anyway, L'Hôpital's rule (and the fact that the derivative of ln(x) is equal to 1/x) can be used to show that the asymptotic limit of f(n)/g(n) is equal to the asymptotic limit of log(f(n))/log(g(n)).

Comment: But yes, if you have a particular algorithm that takes at most, say, `n^2 + 2*n + 5` steps when given an input of size `n`, then it'd be `O(n^2)`  When you add one more step -- calculating the log -- so that it takes `n^2 + 2*n + 6` steps, this is still O(n^2).  The point is that, in general, unless the extra work scales with the size of the input, then adding extra work just adds a constant to the Big O -- and Big O notation ignores constants.

Comment: @Peter The OP says in the comments he's talking about "time complexity" . . . although it seems like maybe he's conflating the time complexity with the asymptotic limit of the function itself.

Comment: @Tim Goodman - the last comment from Apy that I can see is about asymptotic limits.   However, I do agree s/he is conflating concepts.

Comment: @Peter, yes you are correct, I was wrong in explaining the question correctly and was conflating them in comments. But now I understand both the concepts about limits and time complexity. Thanks for taking the time to explain. Now, can you write them as an answer, so that I mark this question as solved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now that comments have revealed that this question is about asymptotic limits rather than about algorithmic complexity .....

You can use L'Hôpital's rule (information is in any basic text on differential calculus) and the fact that the derivative of `ln(x)` (natural logarithm) is `1/x` to show that the asymptotic limit of `f(n)/g(n)` is equal to the asymptotic limit of `log(f(n))/log(g(n))`.

Note that this has little or nothing to do with algorithmic complexity though.

Comment: What if `log(g(n))=0`?

Comment: @user2154420   The point is calculating an asymptotic limit of an indeterminate functional form.    L'Hopital's rule is a theorem that says the limiting value of `f(x)/g(x)` at a point where `g(x)` is zero is equivalent to `f'(x)/g'(x)`  (i.e. the ratio of the derivatives at that point `x`).   If the first derivative still gives division by zero, the second derivative can be used, and so on.   At points where `log(g(n))` is zero, one of its derivatives is not.

Answer (score -2):

If we take "*f* in *O(g)*" to mean "there exists a **positive** real number *M* and real number *N* such that *|f(n)|≤Mg(n)* for all *n>N*", then the claim can fail if *g(n)=1*.

**Counterexample:** let *f(n)=a* and *g(n)=1*, where *a* is the base of the logarithm.
Then *f(n)* is in *O(g(n))* since

*a=|f(n)|≤ag(n)=a*

for all *n>0*. However, there is no (positive) real number *M* and real number *N* such that

*1=|log(f(n))|≤Mlog(g(n))=0*

for all *n>N*, so *log(f(n))* is **not** in *O(log(g(n)))*.

However, the claim holds for more general *g(n)*:

**Claim:** If *log(g(n))>0* for all *n>K*, *f(n)>0* for all *n>L*, and *f(n)* is in *O(g(n))*, then *log(f(n))* is in *O(log(g(n))*.

**Proof:** Since *f(n)* is in *O(g(n))* there is a positive real number *M* and real number *N* such that

*|f(n)|≤Mg(n)*

for all *n>N*. Now apply *log* to both sides, noting this function is monotone, to get

*|log(f(n))|=log(|f(n)|)≤log(Mg(n))=log(M)+log(g(n))*

for all *n>max(N, L)*.
Since *log(g(n))>0* for *n>K*, there exists a *B>0* such that

*log(M)≤Blog(g(n))=log((g(n))^B)*

for *n>K*. Hence,

*|log(f(n))|≤log(M)+log(g(n))≤Blog(g(n))+log(g(n))=(B+1)log(g(n))*

for all *n> max(N,L,K)*, so *log(f(n))* is in *O(log(g(n)))*.

Comment: Could someone explain why this is getting downvotes?

Comment: The question is off-topic on SO as it doesn't concern a programming related issue and should be close-voted as such and not be answered

Comment: That makes sense why the question should be closed or downvoted, but why are the answers being punished for that?

Comment: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions) - Also look at the 2nd highest-voted answer with regards to the clean-up scripts

Comment: Ah okay. So what should I do with the answer? Delete it? Also, for future reference do algorithm theory questions belong to some other particular stack exchange site?

Comment: This probably should have been posted on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I shouldn't delete it, then it seems like I will just get repeatedly punished with downvotes for a site customs reason instead of an incorrect answer reason. I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: It also seems odd because the question isn't flagged as off topic as far as I can tell nor does it have downvotes. The existence of the asymptotic complexity tag would have me think it's a valid question for the site...

Comment: From the tag excerpt: "*Questions must relate to programming. For theoretical Computer Science questions, please ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/*"

Comment: This all seems ridiculous looking at the precedent set by the questions listed as related to this one. Should we all march into all of these questions and downvote every answer because the original questions are now deemed "off topic"?